# How to enable and disable document event handler (specifically click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I have a button, clicking on which, I have to enable the click event handler on the entire document. Once someone clicks now, I want to capture the dom selector of that element and disable the event handler again.

Is this question asked already? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything relevant. There are a lot of solutions on enabling or disabling event handler on a particular element, but I have to do it over the entire document. Here is my code -

JavaScript -

```
<script>
  var select_target = false;
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (select_target) {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "#FDFF47";
      var text = $(event.target).text();
      console.log(text) //This text should be the DOM Selector, which I'm not able to retrieve
      select_target = false
    }
  })
  $('.select_target').click(function() {
    select_target = true
  })
</script>
```

HTML -

```
<!-- Lot of code from the other parts of the webpage -->
<button name="ignore" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md m-1 select_target">
  Select Target
</button>
<!-- Lot of code from the other parts of the webpage -->
```

This gives me `Select Target` as the output instead of the DOM Selector of the element, which I wasn't expecting to be the target button in the first place, but whatever I click after clicking the select target button.

I know the code looks clumsy, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks like it does that already.

Comment: Seem to work just fine for me

Comment: "*This text should be the DOM Selector*" - it's no longer possible to do this with jquery.  `$(event.target)` will give you the jquery object of the button clicked (`.text()` will give you text not the selector) but there's no way to know what the *original* selector was that wired up the event (be it `$(".select_target")` or `$(".btn")` for example)

Comment: You could try `$("*").off("click")` to *remove* all the click handlers, but you won't be able to add them back.

Comment: The issue with `$(document).click(function(event) { if (select_target) {` is that the click event only bubbles up to `document` *after* it has fired (and not handled / stopPropagation'd)

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to handle this would be to display an overlay over the whole page, similar to a modal dialog's background.  This will then be the first place that click events hit.  It can be transparent.

Comment: @freedomn-m Looks like a good idea of displaying an overlay over the whole page. Can you give me an example for the same using the code snippet I've given in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following code does what I'm expecting. It's for everyone who wants a similar thing to happen i.e., To be able to select the element from the page on which you want to perform specific operations with a clean and modifiable code.

Javascript -

```
<script>
  var select_target = false;
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (select_target) {
      event.preventDefault(); //If you click a link or a button, this helps in just selecting it and it won't perform it's default operation.
      var text = $(event.target).text();
      console.log(text)
      select_target = false;
    }
  })
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body *").mouseenter(function(el){
      if(select_target){
        $(el.target).addClass("red-hover-box"); //To highlight the elements on hover
      }
    })
    $("body *").mouseout(function(el){
      if(select_target){
        $(el.target).removeClass("red-hover-box"); //To remove the highlight on the elements. This will keep the element highlighted if you click on it, since the select_target's value would be false after the click.
      }
    })
  })
  $('.select_target').click(function() {
    e.stopPropagation(); //To prevent the click on the button to be handled by the event listener.
    select_target = true
  })
</script>
```

CSS -

```
.red-hover-box{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

HTML -

```
<!-- Lot of code from the other parts of the webpage -->
<button name="ignore" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md m-1 select_target">
  Select Target
</button>
<!-- Lot of code from the other parts of the webpage -->
```

I'm still now able to figure out on how to get a unique identifier for the HTML element that has been clicked, and would update this answer once it's been figured out.

Thanks!